# How to fix “Unable to find free port” error in Java (android)

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium Chromedriver and whenever I am running this on a device I am getting the below error.

```
 2019-09-13 23:10:58.671 11984-11984/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 11984
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a free port
```

Can anybody help out in this?